# How to know when android phone connected adb

Tags: android

I need do something when phone connected adb.How to know this action?

I think maybe have one broadcast,but I can't find it.

my mean is in phone know connected state,not pc

Comment: This could use some clarification. Do you mean how can you tell *within an android application* or *from my PC* or what?

Comment: i need know this connected state in phone,not pc

Answer (score 15):

you can use `adb devices`

[Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Answer (score 7):

run 'adb devices' in command line client, if your phone has been connected adb, it will show you like this:

```
List of devices attached 
0163C00D17036020    device
```

note: if you have not configed the 'adb' environment path, cd to android-sdk/platform-tools/,
      then run it.

Answer (score 3):

Run

> `adb devices -l`

It will show you more information

Answer (score 0):

for automation you can use from adb shell. if return a error you can underestand that a device connect to your adb.
for example:

[click_me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BFnj.png)

Comment: You can insert the image directly, or even better, you can type in the text from the terminal, so it will be easier to copy commands.