# Visual Studio does not show "Android Local Devices" menu

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui

I'm using visual studio 2022 and MAUI to develop a Android APP, but I can't find the menu for selecting my local Android Device.
I already connected my device with my desktop computer via USB, and setted USB debug mode.
Screenshot:

[image]

You can see there are Android Emulators menu, iOS local devices menu and so on, but there isn't Android Emulators button. How can I add it manually? I already tried restart VS.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754535/how-to-know-when-android-phone-connected-adb, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized?rq=2

Comment: You should work towards establishing a connection between the PC and the device. ( I mean, it is not the VS)

Comment: Make sure that `USB Device Connectivity` is installed (`VS Installer -> Modify -> Individual components`). Then in the `Tools` menu you should have `Android -> Android SDKs and Tools`. In the `Tools` tab, open up `Extras` and make sure that `Google USB driver` is installed. Otherwise, select it and let VS install it

Comment: May I ask if you have solved this question? You may refer to [Set up Android device for debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/device/setup). Remember the following steps : [Enable developer mode on the device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/device/setup#enable-developer-mode-on-the-device), [Enable USB debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/device/setup#enable-usb-debugging) and [Connect the device to the computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/device/setup#connect-the-device-to-the-computer).

Comment: @Jimi I tried these, still not working. Actually, I followed the official documentation from Microsoft as Liqun Shen mentioned.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT nope, I followed the doc you refered, but still not working.

Comment: @H.A.H. My android device pops a promt saying that it's connected to USB debug, so I guess it's connected correctly. Shouldn't VS show a empty list like the "iOS local devices" ? I don't have any iOS devices connected, but the iOS menu is right here.

Comment: @Nowayout _but there isn't Android Emulators button..._ Why you need a  Android Emulators button? Your local android device is Tablet H-DPI 13.5

Comment: @H.A.H. Yes, please give me a screenshot. So it's a normal behavior for VS to not showing Android Local Devices? I assume there would be a "Anroid Local Devices" button since there is a "iOS local Devices" button.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT. I need a "Android Local Devices" button, Tablet H-DPI is my android emulator.

Comment: @Nowayout Got it. Have you tried another android device?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT. Yes,  a tablet and a cell phone

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the visual studio and upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: Have you found the Android local device?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT still not. I tried upgrading to the latest.

Comment: Run ```adb devices```  in Tools -> Android -> Android Adb Command Prompt. Is there any connected device to show?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT nothing. I tried my third device, it's working now. So I guess the problem is with the devices ( I tried two before).

Comment: Well, I agree with you. Different brands or types of devices may have different behaviors.

Comment: As the doc says, _The steps in this article are written generically, to work on as many devices as possible. If you can't find these settings on your device, consult your device manufacturer's documentation._ So you may consult the manufacturer's document.

Comment: Mine was there, and I made a change to my android colors xml file, got some weird build error so I closed and reopened VS and when it came back up my local android menu item was gone.

Comment: Also I want to add that in my situation Ive been developing a .net maui app on local android devices for weeks now without issue until suddenly the menu item disappeared for me. So in my case I know for sure that the devices are setup for debug with VS because Ive been actively developing that way.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you don't have any notifications on your connected phone that needs to be acknowledged once you connect.

In my case, I needed to acknowledge that my phone connection would be used for file transfer. Once I did that, the device showed up in visual studio.

You probably already figured it out, but I am adding this answer incase someone else runs into the same issue.